# SASS code and its corresponding asm code in kernel

Tags: assembly, cuda

I have written the following one line cuda PTX instruction using `asm volatile`

```
__global__ void add( uint32_t a, uint32_t b )
{
  uint32_t c = 0;
  asm volatile("add.u32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=r"(c) : "r"(a), "r"(b) );
  printf("sink=%d\n", c);
}
```

With this kernel call

```
add<<< 1, 1 >>>( 1,2 );
```

and this compilation command

```
nvcc -arch=sm_70 -Xptxas -O3,-v,-dlcm=ca -o test1 test1.cu
```

I see this sass code

```
    code for sm_70
            Function : _Z6addjj
    .headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM70 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM70)"
    /*0000*/                   IMAD.MOV.U32 R1, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x28] ;   /* 0x00000a00ff017624 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fd000078e00ff */
    /*0010*/              @!PT SHFL.IDX PT, RZ, RZ, RZ, RZ ;             /* 0x000000fffffff389 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe200000e00ff */
    /*0020*/                   IMAD.MOV.U32 R0, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x160] ;  /* 0x00005800ff007624 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe200078e00ff */
    /*0030*/                   IADD3 R1, R1, -0x8, RZ ;                  /* 0xfffffff801017810 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe40007ffe0ff */
    /*0040*/                   MOV R4, 0x0 ;                             /* 0x0000000000047802 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe40000000f00 */
    /*0050*/                   IADD3 R0, R0, c[0x0][0x164], RZ ;         /* 0x0000590000007a10 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe40007ffe0ff */
    /*0060*/                   IADD3 R6, P0, R1, c[0x0][0x20], RZ ;      /* 0x0000080001067a10 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe40007f1e0ff */
    /*0070*/                   MOV R5, 0x0 ;                             /* 0x0000000000057802 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fc60000000f00 */
    /*0080*/                   IMAD.X R7, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x24], P0 ;     /* 0x00000900ff077624 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe200000e06ff */
    /*0090*/                   STL [R1], R0 ;                            /* 0x0000000001007387 */
                                                                         /* 0x0001ee0000100800 */
    /*00a0*/                   MOV R20, 0x0 ;                            /* 0x0000000000147802 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fe40000000f00 */
    /*00b0*/                   MOV R21, 0x0 ;                            /* 0x0000000000157802 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fd00000000f00 */
    /*00c0*/                   CALL.ABS.NOINC 0x0 ;                      /* 0x0000000000007943 */
                                                                         /* 0x001fea0003c00000 */
    /*00d0*/                   EXIT ;                                    /* 0x000000000000794d */
                                                                         /* 0x000fea0003800000 */
    /*00e0*/                   BRA 0xe0;                                 /* 0xfffffff000007947 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fc0000383ffff */
    /*00f0*/                   NOP;                                      /* 0x0000000000007918 */
                                                                         /* 0x000fc00000000000 */
            ......................
```

I know that compiler optimizes things, however, I expect to see 2 loads, 1 add and 1 store.

What should I do in order to see that? Also, which sass instruction exactly corresponds to my `add.u32` instruction?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question: Why `volatile`?  It's a pure function of the inputs so you can drop `volatile` and let it be hoisted out of loops, for example.

Comment: Why should there be loads  for passed arguments or stores for a call?

Comment: @PeterCordes: it really doesn't matter. I tested and got the same code.

Comment: Yeah, of course you do *in this case* where you do use the result so it can't optimize away, and where it's not called repeatedly with the same inputs so there's no opportunity for the compiler to  reuse the same result.  The point is to not use `volatile` where you don't need it so these optimizations could happen with different surrounding code, instead of  running  the `asm` statement one for each time the source runs it.  (Of course normally you don't want inline asm at all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CUDA kernel call involves pass-by-value of the kernel parameters.  These parameters (as part of the kernel call mechanism) get passed to the device for use by device code in [**constant memory**](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-parameters).

Therefore your `a` and `b` arguments will be expected to be found in constant memory, by any device code that needs them.

> I expect to see 2 loads, 1 add and 1 store

Those are all there, roughly speaking.  In some cases its easier to work backward, since we don't know a-priori which registers the compiler will use for which items in your code.

Your `printf` statement (a function call) is evidently serviced by this call:

```
/*00c0*/                   CALL.ABS.NOINC 0x0 ;                      /* 0x0000000000007943 */
```

That function call will require a "calling frame" of some sort.  It will expect some pattern of stack, local memory, and/or register population to do its work.  We see the only local store in your kernel just previous to that:

```
/*0090*/                   STL [R1], R0 ;                            /* 0x0000000001007387 */
```

therefore we can surmise at this point that the result of the add operation must have ended up in register R0.  We'll use this information to quickly determine the flow path of the add instruction you are asking about.  Our next question then is "which add instruction deposited a result in R0?"  That would appear to be this one:

```
/*0050*/                   IADD3 R0, R0, c[0x0][0x164], RZ ;         /* 0x0000590000007a10 */
```

(The first operand is always the destination operand, and no other add operation in your kernel has R0 as destination).  We know that this add must somehow add `a` and `b` together. We also now know that `a` and `b` will be expected to be loaded **from constant memory**.  And we see that this instruction is indeed taking one of its operands from constant memory:

```
/*0050*/                   IADD3 R0, R0, c[0x0][0x164], RZ ;         /* 0x0000590000007a10 */
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                         constant memory operand
```

So one of the loads (it is either `a` or `b`,  I don't know which, but I am guessing `b` based on 0x164) is right there in the add instruction of interest.  The other load must also be coming from constant memory, where is that?  We also note from the above instruction that the "other" operand appears to be already in R0 (because R0 is also the first source operand, in addition to being the destination operand).  So we are looking for an instruction that pulls something from constant memory, presumably "near" address 0x164, and places it in R0. That is here:

```
/*0020*/                   IMAD.MOV.U32 R0, RZ, RZ, c[0x0][0x160] ;  /* 0x00005800ff007624 */
```

So we have covered the 2 loads (both from constant, because they are kernel parameters), the add, and the store.

You might ask what are the rest of the instructions doing?  I'm not going to try to explain each one (because I can't) but I think they fall into 2 general categories:

1. Creating any necessary indexing that is needed.  This kernel probably doesn't need much if any indexing, but there is some indexing being created for R1, because it is used to create the address of the local store operation.  Therefore you could follow the instructions setting up R1, and presume that they are involved in "stack" indexing.  This is pursuant to item 2 below:
2. Set up the "calling frame" for the `printf` function call.  This function call may have expectations about data in registers, local memory, and stack (a form of local memory on the GPU - R1 is probably effectively indexing into the stack).  For example, R4, R5, R20, and R21 are all being set to zero by your kernel code, but other than that they are not used by any instructions in your kernel code.  Therefore I would guess that this is part of setting up the "calling frame" for the `printf` function call.

Aside: Constant memory (in SASS code) manifests in "banks".  A constant memory reference consists of a bank followed by an offset:

```
c[0x0][0x164]
 bank offset
```

The GPU uses different banks for different purposes.  For example if you compiled kernel code with references to an ordinary `__constant__` memory entity, I'm reasonably sure you'd see a different bank being referenced than the one here (0x0).  So we could surmise that the GPU uses bank 0 of constant memory for kernel parameters.  But this is not well documented to my knowledge.  Some [historical information](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#banked-constant-state-space-deprecated) about constant banks is in the PTX guide.  [Here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1069681/cuda-programming-and-performance/ptxas-error-file-uses-too-much-global-constant-data-/post/5418719/#5418719) is an additional short write-up on constant memory by njuffa.

Comment: Thank you very much for in-depth explanation. I wrote that `printf` to override compiler optimizations. Otherwise the compiler will discard the asm because destination variable is not used anymore. Is that a good way? Or I have to use nvcc with debug symbols (no opt)?

Comment: I think [its a good way](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1068891/cuda-programming-and-performance/help-understanding-the-differences-in-nvprof-dram-read-write-throughput/post/5414451/#5414451).  Inspecting debug code is even less fun than inspecting optimized SASS code, IMO.  You may have a different view, depending on your appetites.

Comment: @mahmood: When compiling for "normal" CPUs (not GPUs), it works fairly reliably to assign a result to `volatile int sink = ...;` to force the compiler to materialize it.  Or you can use inline asm like `asm("" :: "r"(var))` to force `var`'s value to exist in a register at that point.  Neither of those prevent CSE across loop iterations (e.g. it could turn into a loop that stores the same register `n` times instead of recomputing) but when you don't have a loop a `volatile` local works great and disturbs the asm less than a function call.  IDK if any of this applies to `nvcc`.